# can't get the meaning of return case_of(word)(correct(word.lower()))

Tags: python, scipy, nltk

```
def correct(word):


    """
    Get the best correct spelling for the input word
    """
    # Priority is for edit distance 0, then 1, then 2
    # else defaults to the input word itself.
    candidates = (known(edits0(word)) or 
                  known(edits1(word)) or 
                  known(edits2(word)) or 
                  [word])
    return max(candidates, key=WORD_COUNTS.get)

def correct_match(match):


    """
    Spell-correct word in match, 
    and preserve proper upper/lower/title case.
    """
    
    word = match.group()
    def case_of(text):
        """
        Return the case-function appropriate 
        for text: upper, lower, title, or just str.:
            """
        return (str.upper if text.isupper() else
                str.lower if text.islower() else
                str.title if text.istitle() else
                str)
    return case_of(word)(correct(word.lower()))

    
def correct_text_generic(text):
    """
    Correct all the words within a text, 
    returning the corrected text.
    """
    return re.sub('[a-zA-Z]+', correct_match, text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at `case_of(word)(correct(word.lower()))` from inside out:

1. `word.lower()` will turn `word` in lowercase
2. `correct(word.lower())` will return *best correct spelling*
3. `case_of(word)` will return some function, e.g. `str.upper` or `str.lower`, etc. based on what case original `word` was
4. `case_of(word)(correct(word.lower()))` will return suggested *best correct spelling* in the original case of the `word`